# Using Maven to make pdfs from fo files

Tags: maven, pdf-generation, apache-fop

I'm having trouble finding out how I can make PDF files from a set of FO files using Maven. There appears to be a Maven FOP plugin but the documentation has no examples and no description of how to actually use the plugin. Googling for examples turned up nothing.

You might be tempted to recommend the docbkx plugin to do the whole thing from the Docbook source files, but I've already tried that and cannot get it to work with custom titlepages.

Any advice? Anyone using this that knows how to specify the source files and the output directory?

Thank you!

Alan

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://www.banapple.de/display/BANAPPLE/maven-fop-plugin

```
<plugins>
  ...
<plugin>
  <groupId>de.banapple.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-fop-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <configuration>
    <inputFiles>
      <basedir>src/main/xml</basedir>
    </inputFiles>
    <xslFile>src/main/xsl-fo/foobar.xsl</xslFile>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
...
  </plugins>
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually found that yesterday, but it seems that I have to manually install it, so I shied away from it.